# python no module name pika when importing pika

Tags: python, pika, python-pika

I installed pika for python running on a mac

```
sudo pip install pika==0.9.8
```

I make sure is installed, this is the response when trying to reinstall,

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pika==0.9.8 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

but when i import pika on a *.py I get,

> ImportError: No module named pika

my python version

```
python --version
Python 2.7.5
```

how to make this module recognised by Python?
thanks!

edit 1

I call the import like this

```
import pika
```

which gives the error,
I can fix this temporaritly with,

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

So how to make the path permanent? thanks!

Comment: You should use [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv).

Comment: @KaranGoel thanks, i just do "import", also if i export the path it works temporarily, but if i start CLI again, i have to export path to make it work, cheers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add that export command to your ~/.bash_login file.

Answer (score 8):

More likely you are running several versions of pip and python. Check your 'pip' and 'python' versions - you should use a 'pip' version corresponding to your 'python' version:

```
# python --version
Python 2.7.5
# pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py3.4.egg (python 3.4)
```

As you can see 'pip' will install modules for a python version different from the one I'm using.
I used 'pip2' command for 'python2' (use pip3 for python3):

```
# pip2 install pika
```

Answer (score 5):

Download and run pip from here:

https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html

and then open command window and goto the Scripts folder of the installed python in C and type the following command:

`C:\Python34\Scripts>pip install pika`

Answer (score 5):

```
git clone https://github.com/pika/pika.git
cd pika
python setup.py install

Installs pika 1.0.1b with 2.7
```

or

```
apt install python3
apt install python3-pip
pip3 install pika
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to Scripts in your python folder and drag and drop pip.exe on command prompt and  type install pika.

eg- C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe install pika

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to this problem in Windows. Package was installed successfully but python show me that error.
First of all I uninstall the package using cmd command `pip3 uninstall moduleName`.
Then based on python documentation I run command `python -m pip install moduleName` and my problem solved!

Here is the documentation: [Installing Python Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html)