# ImportError: No module named flask

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv

I installed virtualenv, activated it, and installed flask.
So I have three folders: Include, Scripts and Lib. This last folder contains the site-packages folder, that contains flask folder.

If I put my app.py (simple Hello World app) inside "site-packages" folder, I don't get this error. But if put out of this three folder, but inside my flask_environment, I get this error.

Is something going wrong here?

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Flask\flask_env\app.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ImportError: No module named flask
```

Comment: So, with your environment activated, you get an error when you execute: `python -c 'import flask'`  Also, can you show a stripped down version of your module that produces this error?

Comment: Are any of your files/folders called `flask`? If so this may confuse the import call.

Comment: Ffisegydd, I created a Flask folder to run virtualenv inside and to create flask_env folder

Comment: @user3159162 That tells you that flask is installed correctly.  You should start the python interpreter and enter your script one line at a time, it should reproduce the error by the time you get to line 3

Comment: @leandrotk make sure you activate your virtualenv before running the python file.

Answer (score 7):

Please make sure you have activated virtual environment before running python file.

```
. venv/bin/activate
```

Comment: true, was making the same mistake - running it before activating my virtualenv.

Comment: if you are on linux/ubuntu run your virtualenv using `source venv/bin/activate`

Answer (score 3):

try this command in the terminal instead of selecting 'run code':

```
 python3 'insert your file name here without the quotes'
```

Answer (score 2):

check this stack answer, only instead of pika you have to type flask:

[python no module name pika when importing pika](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19673669/python-no-module-name-pika-when-importing-pika/27987966#27987966)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using python3 you have to change a little bit your wsgi file.

I changed my xx.wsgi from using execfile() to using exec(). Here is what it looks like when it finally worked.

```
activate_this = '/opt/flask/project_name/py3venv/bin/activate_this.py'
exec(open(activate_this).read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/opt/flask/project_name')

from project_app_name import app as application
```

Answer (score 1):

run as `python3 <file_name>`

EX: python3 api.py